# Cross entropy IndexError Dimension out of range

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, cross-entropy

I'm trying to train a GAN in some images, I followed the tutorial on pytorch's page and got to the following code, but when the crossentropy function is applyed during the training it returns the error below the code:

```
import random
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.utils.data
import torchvision.datasets as torch_dataset
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torchvision.utils as vutils
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from IPython.display import HTML

seed = 1
print("Random Seed: ", seed)
random.seed(seed)
torch.manual_seed(seed)
images_folder_path = "./images/"

batch_size = 128
image_size = 256
n_channels = 1
z_vector = 100
n_features_generator = 64
n_features_discriminator = 64
num_epochs = 5
lr = 0.0002
beta1 = 0.5

dataset = torch_dataset.ImageFolder(
    root=images_folder_path, transform=transforms.Compose(
        [
            transforms.Grayscale(num_output_channels=1),
            transforms.Resize(image_size),
            transforms.CenterCrop(image_size),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize(0.5, 0.5)
         ]
    )
)

dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=0)

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if (torch.cuda.is_available()) else "cpu")

def weights_init(m):
    classname = m.__class__.__name__
    if classname.find('Conv') != -1:
        nn.init.normal_(m.weight.data, 0.0, 0.02)
    elif classname.find('BatchNorm') != -1:
        nn.init.normal_(m.weight.data, 1.0, 0.02)
        nn.init.constant_(m.bias.data, 0)


class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.main = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(z_vector, n_features_generator * 8, 4, 1, 0, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(n_features_generator * 8),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(n_features_generator * 8, n_features_generator * 4, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(n_features_generator * 4),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(n_features_generator * 4, n_features_generator * 2, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(n_features_generator * 2),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(n_features_generator * 2, n_features_generator, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(n_features_generator),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(n_features_generator, n_channels, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.Tanh()
        )

    def forward(self, inputs):
        return self.main(inputs)

class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Discriminator, self).__init__()
        self.main = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(n_channels, n_features_discriminator, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(n_features_discriminator, n_features_discriminator * 2, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(n_features_discriminator * 2),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(n_features_discriminator * 2, n_features_discriminator * 4, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(n_features_discriminator * 4),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(n_features_discriminator * 4, n_features_discriminator * 8, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(n_features_discriminator * 8),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(n_features_discriminator * 8, 1, 4, 1, 0, bias=False),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

    def forward(self, inputs):
        return self.main(inputs)

netG = Generator().to(device)
if device.type == 'cuda':
    netG = nn.DataParallel(netG)
netG.apply(weights_init)
print(netG)

netD = Discriminator().to(device)
if device.type == 'cuda':
    netD = nn.DataParallel(netD)
netD.apply(weights_init)
print(netD)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

fixed_noise = torch.randn(64, z_vector, 1, 1, device=device)

real_label = 1.
fake_label = 0.

optimizerD = optim.Adam(netD.parameters(), lr=lr, betas=(beta1, 0.999))
optimizerG = optim.Adam(netG.parameters(), lr=lr, betas=(beta1, 0.999))

img_list = []
G_losses = []
D_losses = []
iters = 0

print("Starting Training Loop...")
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i, data in enumerate(dataloader, 0):
        netD.zero_grad()
        real_cpu = data[0].to(device)
        b_size = real_cpu.size(0)
        label = torch.full((b_size,), real_label, dtype=torch.float, device=device)
        output = netD(real_cpu).view(-1)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        errD_real = criterion(output, label) # ERROR HAPPENS HERE
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        errD_real.backward()
        D_x = output.mean().item()

        noise = torch.randn(b_size, z_vector, 1, 1, device=device)
        fake = netG(noise)
        label.fill_(fake_label)
        output = netD(fake.detach()).view(-1)
        errD_fake = criterion(output, label)
        errD_fake.backward()
        D_G_z1 = output.mean().item()
        errD = errD_real + errD_fake
        optimizerD.step()

        netG.zero_grad()
        label.fill_(real_label)
        output = netD(fake).view(-1)
        errG = criterion(output, label)
        errG.backward()
        D_G_z2 = output.mean().item()
        optimizerG.step()

        if i % 50 == 0:
            print('[%d/%d][%d/%d]\tLoss_D: %.4f\tLoss_G: %.4f\tD(x): %.4f\tD(G(z)): %.4f / %.4f'
                  % (epoch, num_epochs, i, len(dataloader),
                     errD.item(), errG.item(), D_x, D_G_z1, D_G_z2))

        G_losses.append(errG.item())
        D_losses.append(errD.item())

        if (iters % 500 == 0) or ((epoch == num_epochs-1) and (i == len(dataloader)-1)):
            with torch.no_grad():
                fake = netG(fixed_noise).detach().cpu()
            img_list.append(vutils.make_grid(fake, padding=2, normalize=True))

        iters += 1
```

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "G:/Pastas Estruturadas/Conhecimento/CEFET/IA/SpectroGAN/dcgan.py", line 137, in 
errD_real = criterion(output, label)

File "C:\Users\Ramon\anaconda3\envs\vision\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 722, in _call_impl

result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Ramon\anaconda3\envs\vision\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py", line 948, in forward

ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction)

File "C:\Users\Ramon\anaconda3\envs\vision\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 2422, in cross_entropy

return nll_loss(log_softmax(input, 1), target, weight, None, ignore_index, None, reduction)

File "C:\Users\Ramon\anaconda3\envs\vision\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 1591, in log_softmax

ret = input.log_softmax(dim)

IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: can you print your `output` and `label` shape

Comment: output shape torch.Size([20, 1, 13, 13]) label shape torch.Size([20])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model's output is not consistent with your criterion.

**If you want to keep the model and change the criterion:**

Use [`BCELoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCELoss.html#torch.nn.BCELoss) instead of `CrossEntropyLoss`. Note: You will need to cast your labels to float before passing them in. Also consider removing the `Sigmoid()` from the model and using [`BCEWithLogitsLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss).

**If you want to keep the criterion and change the model:**

`CrossEntropyLoss` expects the shape `(..., num_classes)`. So for your 2 class case (real & fake), you will have to predict 2 values for each image in the batch which means you will need to alter the output channels of the last layer in your model. It also expects the raw logits, so you should remove the `Sigmoid()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I removed the sigmoid function in the end of the model.

I had tried using BCELoss, but when I did I had a different error in the same line of code:

ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([20])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([3380]))

Comment: I think I'm gonna keep the criterion and change the shape. As soon as I do I'll return here for feedback.
Thanks :)

Comment: That error suggests that your output shape is not quite right. Please check what your output shape is before you call `.view(-1)` on it.

Comment: I think you're still calling .view(-1) on it. Otherwise it would be of shape (batch_size, C, H, W.); in your case: (1, 1, 13, 13). My guess is that your Discriminator is reducing image size to 13x13 only instead of 1x1 (13*13=169). This could be because your kernel sizes in the conv layers are wrong or you need more conv layers or the images you're passing in are much larger than the model expects.

Comment: Indeed, it is actually torch.Size([20, 1, 13, 13])

Comment: With batch size = 1 it is torch.Size([1, 1, 13, 13])

Comment: Oh, thanksss, it was the images sizes, they were 512x512

Comment: Oh, I tried reducing the images to 256, but the shape of the output is still torch.Size([1, 1, 13, 13]). Think I'll have to add a conv layer